# how to get variable from multipe forms when one of them already submit

Tags: php, forms, post

I have two form

```
<form name='theForm' id='theForm' method="post">
```

and

```
<form id="frmDate" action="?page=absensi" method="post">
```

I submit first form with this

```
<input type="radio" name="keterangan" value="Hadir"  onChange="theForm.submit();" />
```

Second form with this

```
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
        jQuery(function(){ 
            $('#tgl').daterangepicker({
                arrows:true,
                onChange: function(){
                    $('#frmDate').submit();
                }//removed comma here
            });
         });

    </script>
```

I already can get variable from one of forms with this

```
<?php
$keterangan = "";
$date1      = "";
$date2      = "";
if(isset($_POST["keterangan"])){
$keterangan = $_POST["keterangan"];
 }
elseif(isset($_POST["tgl"])){
$dates = explode("-",$_POST[tgl] );
$date1=  date("Y-m-d", strtotime($dates[0]));
if ($dates[0] == $_POST[tgl]){
        $date2 = $date1;
}
else{
$date2=  date("Y-m-d", strtotime($dates[1]));}
} ?>
```

But I don't know how to get variable from forms when one of them already submit.
I have try to manipulate code with this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["keterangan"])){
$keterangan = $_POST["keterangan"];
    if(isset($_POST["tgl"]) and $keterangan<>''){
       $dates = explode("-",$_POST[tgl] );
   $date1=  date("Y-m-d", strtotime($dates[0]));
   if ($dates[0] == $_POST[tgl]){
        $date2 = $date1;
   }
   else{
   $date2=  date("Y-m-d", strtotime($dates[1]));}
       }
 }
elseif(isset($_POST["tgl"])){
$dates = explode("-",$_POST[tgl] );
$date1=  date("Y-m-d", strtotime($dates[0]));
if ($dates[0] == $_POST[tgl]){
        $date2 = $date1;
}
else{
$date2=  date("Y-m-d", strtotime($dates[1]));}
    if(isset($_POST["keterangan"]) and $date1<>'' and $date2<>''){
$keterangan = $_POST["keterangan"];}
} ?>
```

please help me out from my problem. thanks

Comment: also submit the second form inside the first form submit..

Answer (score 0):

Use one form instead of two separated and handle the cases on the backend. You can't read the state of one form if another was submitted.

Comment: and then how must i do Simon sagi? Am should to use one form two handle the cases?

Comment: We can help if you can show the whole file or at least the whole form in html. It's hard to figure out anything if I don't know what is there. But basically you can use one form with datepicker and checkbox and send back to you php script both. After that you can decide what to use in your php code.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP is stateless. If you submit a form, you lost the data of the second form.
You must use only one form.